# Gaps appearing in rigged humanoid model form zbrush?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging, import

I imported an .obj model of my character from zbrush into blender. 
After import I joined all the different objects using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and started rigging, all went well until I saw that the deformation cuts the object at the strands where they were joined while animating.

Any advice on how I can make the character into one piece so that it doesn't cut or separate?

Comment: Probably because they have multiple vertices on the same location, which are not connected.